# Best tool to merge Git flow hotfix for multi-module maven projects

Tags: maven, merge, git-flow

Let's say my develop branch is on v 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT, my master is on 1.0.0.
I have to create a hotfix. Using SourceTree's Git Flow menu (or any other tool), I create the hotfix branch from master, I update the poms to v 1.0.0.1 (using mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.0.1), and do the fix.

When I finish the hotfix using Git-Flow I have to merge back to develop branch. This means that the pom files will conflict. In case I have a multi-module project with a large module tree, all poms must be resolved. Other files which were changed in both branches will also conflict.

Considering that during the hotfix there were no changes to the poms, they can be resolved just using the version on the develop branch.

This must be done for every hotfix, but e.g using SourceTree, visually it is hard to distinguish between poms and other conflicted files. It would be nice I could separate those files somehow which I can safely ignore and merge by accepting what is already on the develop branch.

What is the best way for that?

Comment: Are you the only one working on the "develop" branch?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I know is to use a property for a versions instead of literal defining them into the pom file(s). This is available since [Maven 3.5.0](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html).

You can do it like this:

```xml
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.ci</groupId>
  <artifactId>ci-parent</artifactId>
  <name>First CI Friendly</name>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  ...
</project>
```

Now you can build it via:

```
mvn -Drevision=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT clean package
```

But this would mean to define the revision each time you call Maven via command line which is a little bit cumbersome. So you could use the solution via `.mvn/maven.config` file which contains:

-Drevision=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT

You can define the property within the Maven pom itself like this:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.ci</groupId>
  <artifactId>ci-parent</artifactId>
  <name>First CI Friendly</name>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  ...
  <properties>
    <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
  </properties>
</project>
```

This means you have only a single location where the version is defined and not in every module etc.

A multi module setup works also like this where a child of an above parent could look like this:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.ci</groupId>
    <artifactId>ci-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.ci</groupId>
  <artifactId>ci-child</artifactId>
   ...
</project>
```

BUT BE AWARE that you have to use [flatten-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/) in cases where you like to [deploy such artifacts to a repository](http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) or just want to do [`mvn install`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html). This needs to look like this:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.ci</groupId>
  <artifactId>ci-parent</artifactId>
  <name>First CI Friendly</name>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  ...
  <properties>
    <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
  </properties>

 <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>flatten</id>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>flatten</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>flatten.clean</id>
          <phase>clean</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  <modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    ..
  </modules>
</project>
```

That means in the end you have only a single line where the version of your project is being defined and that should reduce this merge issues dramatically.

Please READ the documentation with care!

Please use only `${revision}`, `${changelist}` or `${sha1}` other properties are currently not supported.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question for git flow.

In your scenario you haven't mentioned making changes to the Pom outside of the version but that is a possibility in a hot-fix. Aside from some really nifty git tricks we resolve this by hand.

In our workflows we do a manual merge resolution and then use maven to make sure we have the correct snapshot version set.

```
 mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

Then we run our tests, and call it a day.

I've been reading about`git rerere` and think it could be super helpful here.

> The name stands for "reuse recorded resolution" and as the name implies, it allows you to ask Git to remember how you've resolved a hunk conflict so that the next time it sees the same conflict, Git can automatically resolve it for you.
>   [More here](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html)

This is a super annoying problem for most dev teams, I'm interested to see others solutions!